# jqplot dateAxisRenderer max and tickInterval

Tags: jqplot

There is a date range,eg.2013-07-01 to 2013-07-18.I want to show the date between the two dates.And I also set the min=2013-07-01,max=2013-07-18,tickInterval=7 day.But the X axis will be 2013-07-01,2013-07-08,2013-07-15,2013-07-22.I just want to show the data till 2013-07-18.Can I do something so that the X axis will be 2013-07-01,2013-07-08,2013-07-15,2013-07-18?????Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

If your ticks never change you can tell jqplot to use an array of string as ticks label :

```
var xTicks = ['2013-07-01', '2013-07-08', '2013-07-15', '2013-07-18'];
$.jqplot('chart1', [myData], {
 axes: {
  xaxis: {
   renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, 
   rendererOptions:{
    tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
   },
   ticks: xTicks, 
   tickOptions: {
    angle: -90,
    formatString: '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'
   },
  }
 }
});
```

Please see working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/GFtAr/)

**Edit**

Updated jsFiddle for making xTicks for an array xDates containing all dates from 2013-07-01 to 2013-07-18 [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/GFtAr/2/)

```
var dates = [
 '2013-07-01','2013-07-02','2013-07-03','2013-07-04',
 '2013-07-05','2013-07-06','2013-07-07','2013-07-08',
 '2013-07-09','2013-07-10','2013-07-11','2013-07-12',
 '2013-07-13','2013-07-14','2013-07-15','2013-07-16',
 '2013-07-17','2013-07-18',
];
var nbWeeks = Math.floor(dates.length/7);
var xTicks = [];
xTicks.push(dates[0]);
for(var i = 1; i<=nbWeeks; i++)
 xTicks.push(dates[i*7]);
xTicks.push(dates[dates.length-1]);
```

Comment: Thanks.If there is a array which contains all the dates between the two dates,like '2013-07-01','2013-07-02','2013-07-03','2013-07-04',.....'2013-07-17','2013-07-18'.Can I pass the array info to the ticks attribute.....

Comment: If you pass an array containing all the dates, your xAxis ticks will be make up with all those dates. But if your interval is always 7 days and you are sure to have all your dates contained in your array you can do a little script to make xTicks array from xDates array (see [updated jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/GFtAr/2/) - and edited answer above)